# IF statement to Round values and ignore those with "<"

Tags: excel, if-statement, formula

I have a column of data that has numerical values to two decimal places and also a few values of <0.06.  How do I round the values with two decimal places and only return the value of <0.06 without rounding those with a "<" sing in front of them?

I have not tried anything as I am unsure of houw to use an if statement for two conditions.

Comment: You can start [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2)

Comment: `=IFERROR(ROUND(A1,0),A1)`